# how to target an animated video preview using Ruby and web driver

Tags: ruby, web, driver

On this webpage http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4531394/Victim-led-death-teenage-drug-dealers.html.

The video appears to be playing but not in full until the play button is clicked on. But I want to target the video and be able to add this to my script but there are instances where there are more than one in a webpage e.g.http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html, if you scroll down the page.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated thanks